# Has directive some reset function, which reacts on form reset? Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I have select, which is represent as directive. This select I include to forms. Problem is, that some forms are in modal windows. So I need reset theese directives after hide modal without routing or emitters. Is here some function in directive, which is called by reseting form, which includes this directive?

Thanks guys.